# Not able to stop location listener android?

Tags: android, location, android-library

I am using this [SmartLocation](https://github.com/mrmans0n/smart-location-lib) Library. I am able to stop the service in activity by using the code.

```
SmartLocation.with(this).location().stop();
```

But when i use this library in service , i am able to start but it doesn't stop until i close app. One more thing to note is that when i use `stopService()`.

`OnDestroy()` is also getting called

Rest of service code is here

```
public class locationService extends Service implements OnLocationUpdatedListener,   OnActivityUpdatedListener
 {
    private LocationGooglePlayServicesProvider provider;

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    NotificationManager notificationManager;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        provider = new LocationGooglePlayServicesProvider();
        provider.setCheckLocationSettings(true);

        SmartLocation smartLocation = new SmartLocation.Builder(getApplicationContext()).logging(true).build();

        smartLocation.location(provider).continuous().start(this);
        smartLocation.activity().start(this);

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean stopService(Intent name) {
        return super.stopService(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationUpdated(Location location) {
        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        double lng = location.getLongitude();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityUpdated(DetectedActivity detectedActivity) {
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        SmartLocation.with(this).location().stop();
        stopForeground(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using activity recognition while stopping as i am using service , it wasn't working . So i declared smartlocation instance as global then i stopped it like this `smartLocation.location().stop();`

**Below is my modified code**

```
public class locationService extends Service implements OnLocationUpdatedListener,   OnActivityUpdatedListener
 {
    private LocationGooglePlayServicesProvider provider;

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    NotificationManager notificationManager;
    SmartLocation smartLocation;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        provider = new LocationGooglePlayServicesProvider();
        provider.setCheckLocationSettings(true);

        smartLocation = new SmartLocation.Builder(getApplicationContext()).logging(true).build();

        smartLocation.location(provider).continuous().start(this);
        smartLocation.activity().start(this);

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean stopService(Intent name) {
        return super.stopService(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationUpdated(Location location) {
        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        double lng = location.getLongitude();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityUpdated(DetectedActivity detectedActivity) {
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        smartLocation.location().stop();
        stopForeground(true);
    }
}
```